# the second largest eigenvalue of transfer operators

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, sp.spectral-theory, ergodic-theory

A Gauss map $T$ is mixing and satisfies Lasota-York inequalities. By Henon's theorem, we know that the transfer operator $\hat{T}$ associated with $T$ has a spectral gap. This means there exists a finite-rank projection operator $P$ and an operator $N$ such that the spectral radius of $N$ is not greater than the parameter $\theta \in (0,1)$, which appears in Lasota-York inequalities. We can write the transfer operator $\hat{T}$ as $\hat{T} = P + N$.

The largest eigenvalue of $P$ is equal to $1$ and is simple. Now, we are interested in cases where the second largest eigenvalue of $P$ exists. This eigenvalue is less than $1$ and greater than $\theta$. To explore this, let's consider the eigenvector $h$ associated with the second largest eigenvalue $\lambda$, such that $\hat{T}h = \lambda h$. We can observe that $h$ has a zero mean.

In the $L^2$ space, let's consider the adjoint operator of $\hat{T}$. This is equivalent to saying that there exists a function $g \in L^2$ such that $g \circ T = \lambda g$. This implies that $g$ vanishes on the set of periodic points. However, we should note that although periodic points are dense, it is not sufficient to prove that $g=0$ almost surely since $g$ might lack the required regularity.

Any references related to these concepts are highly appreciated.